# Getting: Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml while I have fabric.properties with apiKey

Tags: android, google-fabric

I am trying to hide apiKey and apiSecret from open source library while still providing buildable sources to Travis continuous integration.

In official documentation is stated [here:](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html#android-projects) that it should work that I have fabric.properties with:

```
apiKey=7dee86d.....e7f76d8e9453
apiSecret=a6cdefeb0a8f....c8a5d9fa2f5f9895931cc2
```

And then I can remove...

```
Remove the Fabric API key element from your AndroidManifest.xml
```

and instead of that...

```
Add the Fabric API key to your fabric.properties: apiKey=fabric_api_key
```

I initialise fabric normally

```
Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics(), Answers())
```

but still I am getting exception:

```
    E/Fabric: Failure onPreExecute()
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml. Add the following tag to your Application element 
        <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.logErrorOrThrowException(ApiKey.java:130)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.getValue(ApiKey.java:67)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:227)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:210)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:467)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:411)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:369)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:340)
        at renetik.android.sample.model.SampleApplication.onCreate(SampleApplication.kt:20)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
E/Fabric: Error dealing with settings
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml. Add the following tag to your Application element 
        <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.logErrorOrThrowException(ApiKey.java:130)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.getValue(ApiKey.java:67)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.initialize(Settings.java:78)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:124)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: this question does neither feature a `Manifest.xml` nor any `build.gradle`. "It is stated" does not sound too relevant, while it crashes... while it even clearly tells what it expects.

Comment: @MartinZeitler what would you like to add ? My whole build gradle and Manifest that are totally unrelated ?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I improved text so maybe now you will understand question... Check it out man ;)

Comment: @MartinZeitler having the exact same issue. The docs literally say that you should remove what you would normally put into the manifest in lieu of adding the api key to a fabric.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` in your build.gradle - even if you are not using Fabric/Crashlytics, say, in debug build - it still needs to run..